# OpenEJB run in Junit without ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb-3.0, openejb

I want to use `openEJB` for my `Junit` test. And I can run it with the `ejb-jar.xml`. But in this case I cannot run my `EJB` application in `jboss` as I do not use `ejb-jar.xml` for settings. Instead I use `annotations`. 
So if I use `ejb-jar.xml` I can not run my application.

below is my ejb-jar.xml file content. It is actually an empty tag.

```
 <ejb-jar/>
```

If I remove `ejb-jar.xml` Junit test fails and it says cannot find the jndi name.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the issue. 
First I moved the ejb-jar.xml to test package from main. 
src > test > resources > META-INF >ejb-jar.xml

This did not help me.

And then I add this property line to my test class.

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
    // Below property actually was missing and caused this problem. I add it then it works fine.
    properties.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath.include", ".*");

    initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
```

Now I can deploy my EJB in Jboss and Junit test for ejb as well.